# using expressjs and handlebarsjs to write out html files

Tags: express, static-html

I have a fairly simply web app that uses `expressjs` and `handlebarsjs` to retrieve and format markdown files and render them as html to the browser. I'd like to write the html output to the disk instead of sending it to the browser ? I know there are static website generators out there, but I'd rather just modify the existing program a tiny bit instead of installing a whole new kitchen sink.

Answer (score 0):

The standard filesystem library should be able to do this -

```
fs.writeFile(filename, html, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```

Where *filename* is the filename, and *html* is the content you want to write to the file.

See the [filesystem docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback).

Comment: thanks, but that is not what I am looking for. How do I generate the *html* in the first place? With `expressjs` I do `app.render('template', data)` but that sends the html to the browser. I want *that* html to be written to a file.

Comment: How you generate the html will be up to you - but the example shows how you'd write the html to a file. If you want to keep using express and handlebars to generate the html you could send a request to a 'live' page and then save the response body to a file. If this is what you're after I can update my answer with a new code sample.